# JavaScript function to get yesterday date at set time as 00:00:00

Tags: javascript, date, pentaho-spoon

I need to create a javascript function to get yesterdays date and time as midnight 00:00:00. For example `2018-08-03 00:00:00`. The `set.Hours()` function is not working in my case. The script is to be used in `spoon pentaho` data integration. How i can do this. Please help

Comment: What is going wrong ? What do you mean by _The set.Hours() function is not working in my case._ ?

Comment: `The set.Hours() function` you mean the `dateObject.setHours()` function? because `set.Hours` looks like you're "doing it wrong"™

Comment: yes the same function. i have to use this javascript function inside spoon software. So dateObject.setHours() is not working in this software.

Answer (score 2):

You should firstly subtract one day, then set the hours to 00:00:00, e.g.

```js
var d = new Date();
d.setDate(d.getDate() - 1);
d.setHours(0,0,0,0);

console.log(d.toString());
```

If the *setHours* function is not working for you (i.e. not available or broken, which seems very peculiar), then you could use:

```js
var d = new Date();
d.setDate(d.getDate() - 1);
d = new Date(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDate());

console.log(d.toString());

// Or even
var e = new Date();
e = new Date(e.getFullYear(), e.getMonth(), e.getDate() - 1);

console.log(e.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

In Pentaho Data Integration you should always try and use the other steps before resorting to JavaScript, as the performance lowers significantly.

Use a Formula step with the function Today()(which records the current date at 00:00:00) for a column, create a colum with the value -1, and use the Calculator step with the operation DATE A + B Days.

If at some point you want the exact time of the date, you can use the function Now() in the formula step.